# Specify a fie path for External SFTP Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, files, data-export, sftp

I need to drop a file on an External SFTP from Marketing Cloud which I know I can do with a file transfer activity but I can only choose a pre-defined file destination.  In that destination setup in Admin, I don't have a place to specify the file path for an external SFTP like I do for the SFMC Enhanced SFTP.  Any ideas on how I can do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you choose "External SFTP" as the location type, your Url field should have the absolute path to the ftp folder you need to access.

Example: sftp://ftp.domain.com/folderForSFMC/

You can find your folder's absolute path by viewing the folder in an FTP client and right-clicking on the folder to "Copy URL(s) to Clipboard" (that's the option in FileZilla).

Comment: Awesome!I"ll try that.

Comment: this worked.  Thanks so much

Comment: @jake314159 I get an unspecified error on the format you specified above. I had to remove the sftp:// before the server name.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Setup > File Locations > Create

- Location Type: Select External SFTP Site
- Url: sftp.yourdomain.com/yourfolder

**Time Savers**

- No trailing slash required
- no user@ nor sftp:// required
- Impossible to add 'yourfolder' to the filename pattern on your File Transfer Activity in Automation Studio. So for each subfolder you'll have to create a new file location.

In other words, the above config + %%filename.csv%% will work.
Whereas both of the below configs will fail:

- url: sftp.yourdomain.com
  File Transfer Activity filename: /yourfolder/%%filename.csv%%
- url: sftp.yourdomain.com
  File Transfer Activity filename: yourfolder/%%filename.csv%%